# Spring JPA naming query with orderBy doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm using Spring Boot 2, Spring JPA, Spring Data.

I'm trying to get the first result from a table in which I want to sort results by a int property asc.

This is my bean:

```
@Entity
public class DatabaseInstance extends AbstractEntity {

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Supplier supplier;

    NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "INT DEFAULT 0.0")
    private int databaseCount = 0;
```

and this is my repository:

```
@Transactional
public interface DatabaseInstanceRepository extends JpaRepository<DatabaseInstance, Long> {

    public Optional<DatabaseInstance> findFirstOrderByDatabaseCountAsc();

}
```

According to [Spring manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) I can order by property name + asc word. At the same time I want the first result (so i get the instance with the lower databaseCount value).

I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property asc found for type int! Traversed path: DatabaseInstance.databaseCount.
```

I am not able to figure out what's wrong with my method name. Some advice?

Comment: Try `findFirstByOrderByDatabaseCountAsc()`

Comment: It works! @Ranjeet

Comment: Would be nice if you just use the paged and sorted "findAll(Pageable)" method of JpaRepository, that could be used in all cases, with order or not, with the 1st result or more. Just inform you sorting property and the page size 1.